How to make file upload picker start in last used directory?
The file upload picker used in Firefox/Brave/Chrome used to use the last directory you selected. But now it defaults to a "recent files" view.
I rarely need to upload recently modified files. I usually want to upload from the last directory I selected. That used to be the standard functionality in Ubuntu 20.04, but it changed in 22.04.
How do I revert this?
